# Issues accessing attributes of object appended to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, class, attributes

I am attempting to create a room inspection application that appends failed rooms to a list.

**Where I am having trouble is accessing the attributes once the created 'room' object is appended to the empty 'failedRooms' list. All I can manage to do is return where the object is stored in the memory.**

```
class UniRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, roomNumber, balcony, carpet, bedroom, room):
        self.roomNumber = roomNumber
        self.balcony = balcony
        self.carpet = carpet
        self.bedroom = bedroom
        self.room = room

    def printResult(self): #deleted because irrelevant to question.
        


failedRooms = []
print("---------- Globe Apartments Room Checker ----------")
rooms = [UniRoom(roomNumber=input("\nPlease enter the number of the room being graded: "),
                 balcony=input("Please enter the grade of the balcony: "),
                   carpet = input("Please enter the grade of the carpet: "),
                   bedroom = input("Please enter the grade of the bedroom: "),
                   room = input("Please enter the final grade of the room: ").upper()) for i in range(3)]

for r in rooms:
    r.printResult()
    if r.room == 'FAIL':
        print("This room has failed inspection")
        failedRooms.append(r)

print(failedRooms)
```

Apologies if I am not following posting format. I am new to stackoverflow, and attempting to make my first Python project (relatively new to python ~2months experience, mostly spent doing theory)

Would appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the array of failedRooms, not an instance of UniRoom within the array.  You can specify a specific UniRoom within failedRooms using [] like this:

```
print(failedRooms[0])
```

Although it's still just a memory address of an object.  To access properties within UniRoom you can do something like this (slightly modified version of your code).  I am iterating over every failed room added to the failedRooms list, and printing the details from each:

```
class UniRoom(object):
    def __init__(self, room_number, balcony, carpet, bedroom, room):
        self.room_number = room_number
        self.balcony = balcony
        self.carpet = carpet
        self.bedroom = bedroom
        self.room = room

    def print_result(self):  # deleted because irrelevant to question.
        print(self)


failedRooms = []
print("---------- Globe Apartments Room Checker ----------")
rooms = [UniRoom(room_number=i,
                 balcony=90,
                 carpet=80,
                 bedroom=70,
                 room='FAIL') for i in range(3)]

for r in rooms:
    r.print_result()
    if r.room == 'FAIL':
        print("This room has failed inspection")
        failedRooms.append(r)

for failed_room in failedRooms:
    print('room_number: {}'.format(failed_room.room_number))
    print('balcony: {}'.format(failed_room.balcony))
    print('carpet: {}'.format(failed_room.carpet))
    print('bedroom: {}'.format(failed_room.bedroom))
    print('room: {}'.format(failed_room.room))
```

Comment: Excellent! This method works. Thanks!

It makes sense that I should try to access each individual attribute. Will know for next time.